# php - detect if email is sent

Tags: php, email

Im building an automated newsletter, im kinda stuck with this problem.
I need to know if the email was sent or not. Here is my code

```
 @$send = mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

i tried to add it to an if statement but it does not work here is the code.

```
if( @$send = mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message, $headers)){
   //do something
}else{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: put @ before mail. i.e. $send = @mail(....)

Comment: [From the `mail` docs:](http://php.net/mail) *Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise. It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.* - in other words, you cannot detect with PHP if the email was sent.

Comment: -1 for " it gives me an error" but not stating which.

Comment: edited sorry for that! :)

Comment: I believe the problem was that you were checking if $send managed to be set as the output of mail, which would always be true regardless of whether the mail sent successfully or not.

What needed to be done was to either just put the `mail()` statement in the condition or set `$send = mail();` before the if statement and just put `$send` in the condition.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
if(@mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
  echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
}else{
  echo "Mail Not Sent";
}
```

Comment: need to wait for 4 mins more :)

Comment: The acceptance of this answer is a perfect example of why PHP has such a bad reputation.

Comment: This simply checks if the local mail server (or the SMTP configured in php.ini) accepted the outgoing email. The mail server will then try to send the email to the recipient's mail server, but this is done after PHP's mail() returns, as explained in other answers.

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, I'd suggest using a third party mail library ([SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html)...) for sending email instead of the built in `mail` function. Composing mail is more complicated than most people realize, especially if you want to do multipart and/or HTML formatted email.

Secondly, beyond checking if the message was successfully delivered to the first (usually local) email service, it is pretty much impossible to determine if an email was sent. This is due to the way email inherently works and there is little than can be done about it.

The only thing you can (and really should) do, is make sure your system handles bounced emails in a sane way. eg. If an email address continuously bounces, consider unsubscribing the address.

Comment: Thanks brenton for the advice ill use this in the future as of now i just need to know if ive sent the email. wether the user receives it or not. thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

Here's the truth: unfortunately you can't reliably detect if an email was either sent or received: email is not a reliable form of communication.

The result of a call to `mail()` only indicates that PHP was able to send the email to an MTA, but that will not indicate whether or not an email was actually sent or that the recipient actually received it.

If you want more reliability, you have to use something *other* than `mail()`. Although I've never used it, PHPMailer or another SMTP library may give you the returned information from the MTA, which will tell you more about the queued delivery, but without polling for a bounce message (which may or may not be delivered to the sender's inbox) you have no way of telling if a recipient received the email.

Answer (score 2):

**Only for sake of completeness** it should be mentioned that there is a way to send an email via `PHP` and to know whether it is really accepted by receiving MTA (which, again, doesn't mean it is delivered to user or discarded silently after SMTP handshake) or not.

One could theoretically write an SMTP client purely in `PHP`, for example using built-in **Stream functions** like [stream_socket_client](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) in order to talk to receiving MTA via direct raw tcp connections formed in SMTP protocol requests and responses.

General logic of issuing SMTP commands would be like:

```
<?php
$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://fqdn-of-receiving-mta:25", $errno, $errstr, 90);
fwrite($fp, "EHLO LOCALHOST\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "MAIL FROM: youremailaddress@something.tld\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "RCPT TO: recipient@remotedomain.com\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "DATA\r\n");
fwrite(
    $fp,
    "Subject: your subject text\r\n" . 
    "First line of message body\r\n" .
    "At the end of the message body one single period char should be placed before and after EOL character\r\n" .
    "Like this: \r\n" .
    ".\r\n" 
);
```

Of course, this is blatantly incomplete (experienced devs would notice that I wasn't neither listening nor parsing to SMTP responses I'd get). In order for this approach to be used serious re-inventing the wheel in `PHP` language has to be performed.

### How would this be used to detect if email is sent?

Well, you would have at least 3 types of information:

1. whether receiving host is alive and gets email messages at all
2. whether you'r not bounced during handshake (SMTP 5xx responses class)
3. whether you got SMTP `250 2.0.0 Ok` after submitting message text

Again, this is only for educational purposes, don't do this at home unless you're prepared to marry the project of developing standard-compliant SMTP client.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
$send = mail($to,$subject,$msg);
if($send)
{
    echo "Your Account is Successfully Created. You must Activate your account.";
}
else
    echo "Failed to send";
```

Comment: This answer is a copy of the accepted answer, only less accurate (missing @ sign).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a bit more information in @Daya's answer and I want to do bit modification in his answer and that is following:

If the email will send successfully then not an issue but if mail function has error then how could developer will get the error and for that he/she can use `error_get_last()` function for getting last error and the modification is following:

```
if(!$mail) {
  print_r( 'Mailer error: ' . error_get_last());
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

$send = mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message, $headers);

Check the returned value of $sent like  If($send['error_code'] == 0)  { echo "successful"; }  Else { Echo "error"; }

Comment: PHP's `mail` does not return an array