# Sending verification mail before registering user - PHP

Tags: php, user-registration, email-verification

I am currently working on the PHP project in which I have to send the verification mail to the user who register in the site. (Email id is the username).  I am having the following doubt.

- Whether I have to send them the verification email before storing the user in database or after storing the user in database.
- If I send the verification mail to the user after storing user in database what I have to do if the email is not sent from my server. Because user cannot able to re-register with the same email id.

Please help me in this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: you should store in database and also use a flag for email that email has sent or not.

Answer (score 0):

- you have to send mail after registration save details in db with key(that will send with link) and status
  like 0 in database . if they click on that link then delete
  activation key from database and also change status into  1  and on
  login you also need to check user have status 1 if not then you can
  show alert like Mail Confirmation Pending .
- after send mail you can check mail sent or not .check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191446/php-detect-if-email-is-sent)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store the user in database and then send the verification email. In the database keep a field to mark whether user verified the email or not.

Give user an option to resend email verification incase they didn't receive.

Answer (score 0):

As far as from my experience

1. Enter details in DB and then send the verification mail, else your in a situation that you cant verify the user back again.
2. In-case email sending fails from your side, provide a option for the user to request for resending of the verification mail.
3. Maintain a status in the DB whether a user is verified or not, and based on that you can resend the verification mail.